# PTIJ: Forgetting Netilas Yadayim

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

What should a person do if they keep forgetting to dry their hands with a towel after Netilas Yadayim?
The [Tashbetz Katan 287](https://www.ou.org/life/torah/mm_habits/) states that drying hands on one's clothes leads to forgetfulness. So, if one is already forgetting this Halacha, then it seems they are stuck in a Catch-22.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 4):

Ah but the important point is that he meant well, so although he forgot, his intentions were still good.

Indeed, [Orchos Tzaddikim 20:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Orchot_Tzadikim.20.4?ven=Orchot_Tzaddikim,_trans._Seymour_J._Cohen,_Ktav_Pub_House,_1982&lang=bi) writes:

> **אך ישתמש במידת השכחה לשכוח המצוות שעשה**. כי אם יתן לב לזכור מצוותיו ותורותיו, וישכח רעותיו ותחבולותיו – אז יהיה צדיק בעיניו ולא ישוב.
>
> **However, a man should employ the quality of forgetfulness to forget the commandments that he has fulfilled**. For if he sets his mind on remembering the precepts that he has fulfilled and the Torah that he has studied, while forgetting his bad deeds and evil schemes, then he will be a righteous man in his own eyes and will not repent.

So we see sometimes, it is not so bad to forget!!!

The alternative practical approach is to do something that will help him remember, like put on a funny piece of clothing....er...Just be conscious not to put on two pieces of clothing simultaneously as that causes more forgetfulness (See [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 3:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.3.5?ven=Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch,_trans._Rabbi_Avrohom_Davis,_Metsudah_Pub.,_1996&lang=bi))...

I had one more piece of advice, but I forgot....